Should questions on bitcoin theft be closed?
As an example, this is a recent question - Bitcoin theft from Coinbase account being hacked
This is the second or third time I've seen this type of question. It's boils down to someone complaining that they lost their bitcoins. I don't see how this community can do anything about it.
Also, if they should be closed, what reason should be used when flagging/closing?

There's nothing inherently wrong with this question. It's going to be a common problem. 
So why not write one definitive, killer answer explaining exactly what folks can (or can't) do in this situation? It may be true that this community (or anyone, for that matter) can do nothing about it, but that may be an answer in and of itself. Or perhaps there are some remedial steps that can be taken in this event. 
But folks are going to be searching for this stuff… and when they do, I sure would like them to find this site.
This is what we call a "canonical answer", and it's a great way to direct all those problematic questions to a helpful resource you create here… instead of creating an all out moratorium on a perfectly valid issue. 
That's the best way to help users without having to answer the same question over and over. 
